# How to prove that a certain quantity is conserved?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, lagrangian-formalism, metric-tensor, conservation-laws, vector-fields

If one were to consider the following action functional:

$$S = \int dt G_{ij}(\textbf{q}) \cdot \overset{.}{q_i} \overset{.}{q_j}. $$

Given that there exists some vector $v_i$ with the following property:

$$\sum_{i} \frac{\delta G_{jk}}{\delta q_i} v_i+ G_{ij} \frac{\delta v_i}{\delta q_k}+G_{ki} \frac{\delta v_i}{\delta q_j} =0.$$

I assume that $k$ and $j$ are arbitrary indices.

Now consider $$Q_v =\sum_{ij} v_i \cdot \overset{.}{q_i} \cdot G_{ij}$$ and show that $Q_v$ is a conserved quantity.

Edit: This is a typo on my exam

The correct quantity is :
$$\sum_{ij} v_i \overset{.}{q_j}G_{ij}$$

What I tried to do was assume that the motion described by the functional is a real motion, therefore the integrand must make the integral stationary. This means that the integrand must satisfy the Euler-Lagrange equations and doing all the messy algebra yields some condition which makes me able to get rid of the term $\overset{..}{q_i}$ which will be found while deriving $Q_v$.

What I found was that:

$$2\sum_{j} G_{ja} \cdot \overset{..}{q_j}=\sum_{ij} \frac{\delta G_{ij}}{\delta q_a} \cdot \overset{.}{q_i} \overset{.}{q_j}-2 \frac{\delta G_{ia}}{\delta q_j} \overset{.}{q_i} \overset{.}{q_j}. $$

And for $$\frac{d Q_v}{dt}=\sum_{p} ( \sum_{j} v_p G_{pj} \overset{..}{q_p} + \sum_{i} (\frac{\delta v_i}{\delta q_p} G_{ij}+v_i \frac{\delta G_{ij}}{\delta q_p}) \overset{.}{q_p} \overset{.}{q_i} ).$$

However I am stuck now, since there is this term $\overset{.}{q_i}$ which prevents me from using the property of $v_i$, also applying the condition from the EL- equations doesn't work since I have this annoying term $v_p$ in my summation.

Comment: Your third and fifth equations have index errors which may be tripping you up.  (Or they may just be typos.)

Comment: what do you mean index errors in the third?

Comment: I was assuming that it should be $\dot{q}_j$ rather than $\dot{q}_i$.  If it is, then you can show that the quantity is conserved.  If $Q_v$ is really defined as you've written it, then it may well not be a conserved quantity.

Comment: It may very well be a typo since the question is from an old exam by past students :), I will try again and tell you the results

Comment: From an advanced point of view the result is easy, but I do not think you are interested in this type of solution. The First condition says that $v$ is a Killing field of the metric $G$ written in terms of Lie derivative. The equation of motion describes geodesics of $G$. Using the other form of the Killing equation (in terms of covariant derivative), the conservation equation turns out to be trivial.

Comment: I guess from an advanced point of view any question posed on my exams would be easy... I have no knowledge about metrics or Lie derivatives, so although I am interested I lack the knowledge to approach the problem that way.

Comment: @MichaelSeifert with the typo out of the way i found the answer after some manipulation. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HINT:  When proving conservation laws in the Lagrangian formalism, it's usually easier to avoid explicitly introducing second derivatives.  Instead, leave the left-hand side of the Euler-Lagrange equations in the form
$$
\frac{d}{dt} \left[ 2 Q_{ij} \dot{q}_j \right],
$$
and note that
$$
v_i \frac{d}{dt} \left[ 2 Q_{ij} \dot{q}_j \right] = 2 \frac{d}{dt} \left[v_i Q_{ij} \dot{q}_j \right] - 2 Q_{ij} \dot{q}_j \frac{d}{dt} \left[ v_i \right].
$$
(I'm using the Einstein summation convention here, and I would encourage you to do so as well if you're comfortable with it.)